# Do binary networks require every node to be a binary feature or can one node have multiple labels?

Tags: binary, nodes, bayesian, bayesian-networks

So for e.g I have a feature "X" which has 3 possible labels, yes no and maybe. And X directly influences another Feature "Y". In this case do I need to create 3 separate nodes, one for yes, one for no and one for maybe and then draw an edge from each of them to Y? Each new node here will represent one binary variable

As in,

```
Yes --> Y
No --> Y
Maybe --> Y
```

Or simply draw X --> Y, where a single node X will represent the 3 labels yes no and maybe

Im confused at the number of nodes required here and how it will influence the CPT's